# In KOFAX KTA 7.4 how to use and import extrnal .fpr file?

Tags: kofax

I am new to KTA and currently using 7.4 version where i have a question, how we can use and import .fpr project file externally in Transformation Designer 7.4?
There is an option for Import File-Based Project in the Transformation Designer.

[image: KOfax KTA Designer ScreenShot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you answered your own question.  "Import File-Based Project".  That will import the FPR project into the database, which is where you will work with it until you use the "Export to File-Based Project", but typically, at that point, I just use a package.  I'm not sure if there is significant benefit of using a file-based project over a package.  For example, can you import a file based-project into earlier versions, while packages can't?